# Converting a printf(); statement to a cout<<""; statement. C & C++

Tags: c++, c, printf, cout

I am trying to understand printf() but I am only familiar with C++ cout<< statements, would anyone be able to translate the syntax of the printf() statements below? I am just trying to understand what is happening in this snippet of code.

```
void print_section(int n, int z){

    char dots[2*n+1];       // this makes a char array
    memset(dots,':',2*n+1); // this is similar to setfill()
    dots[2*n+1] = 0;

    for(int r = 0; r < n+1; r++){
        printf("%*.s|%.*s\\%.*s/%.*s|\n",z-n,"",r,dots,2*(n-r),dots,r,dots);
    }
    for(int r = n; r >= 0; r--){
        printf("%*.s|%.*s/%.*s\\%.*s|\n",z-n,"",r,dots,2*(n-r),dots,r,dots);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use boost::format as an easy solution

Comment: `dots[2*n+1] = 0;` is writing outside the array - undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How `printf()` works?

If you want to fully understand the working of `printf()` function, then refer this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

In simple words, `"%*.s|%.*s\\%.*s/%.*s|\n"` says that

1. Set field width dynamically and print required amount of `''`
2. Print `|`
3. Set field width dynamically and print required amount of `':'`
4. Print `\`
5. Set field width dynamically and print required amount of `':'`
6. Print `/`
7. Set field width dynamically and print required amount of `':'`
8. Print `|`
9. Print newline character `\n` to go to the next line in console.

Similarly, you can figure out what `"%*.s|%.*s/%.*s\\%.*s|\n"` will print.

## Code conversion

I **assume** that you're pretty familiar with C++. It's better if you use `string` class as you can then easily use `substr()` member function to extract the required `dots` substring to print. You can understand how `setw()` works from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/). The converted code is given below.

```cpp
#include <iostream> // Input.Output
#include <string> // string class
#include <iomanip> // setw() function
int main(){
    const int n=3,z=6;
    std::string _dots(2*n+1,':');
    for(int r = 0; r < n+1; r++){
        std::cout<<std::setw(z-n)<<""<<"|"<<_dots.substr(0,r)<<"\\"<<_dots.substr(0,2*(n-r))<<"/"<<_dots.substr(0,r)<<"|"<<std::endl;
    }
    for(int r = n; r >= 0; r--){
        std::cout<<std::setw(z-n)<<""<<"|"<<_dots.substr(0,r)<<"/"<<_dots.substr(0,2*(n-r))<<"\\"<<_dots.substr(0,r)<<"|"<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Output

```
   |\::::::/|
   |:\::::/:|
   |::\::/::|
   |:::\/:::|
   |:::/\:::|
   |::/::\::|
   |:/::::\:|
   |/::::::\|
```

Comment: Yep, that's the key. Where the *precision* can be controlled by `printf` with the `"%s"` *conversion specifier* to limit the number of characters output, in C++, you have to control the string size itself with `.substr()`. **Note:** you only need `std::string _dots(2*n,':');` -- no need to reserve space for the *nul-terminating* character `:)`

Comment: One bit of extra sneaky worth spending some time on is exactly what happens with the first `"%*.s"`. The associated arguments are `z-n` and `""`, a minimum length to print (padded with spaces because nothing else is specified) and an empty string. `"%s"` would be just print an empty string--basically do nothing--but because of the `*.` that nothing has a minimum width of `z-n` spaces. End result: print `z-n` spaces. I'm not sure that `.` is needed though. I'd love it if anyone could explain if I missed something.